# Adding Flurry in the alertView

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

I have added a Flurry logevent when the ok button of the alertView is clicked.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) 
    {
        NSString *start = @"Start";
        NSString* myLogEvent = [start stringByAppendingString:title.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",myLogEvent);
        [Flurry logEvent:myLogEvent];
    }
}
```

I have logged the event like 2 hours ago. It is still not appearing in my Flurry Login Page. Did i do something wrong?

I know the analytics takes time to appear but the event name should appear in the login page after 45 minutes or so. Am i right? Worried I did something wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage data from Flurry may take up to 7 hours to get reflected on the developer portal. First time Events may take slightly longer.

Edit: If you're using the simulator, please ensure that you press the home button before closing the app. This is required in order to complete the Flurry reporting lifecycle.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: just a qn: I am running the app in the simulator, does it get still recorded?

Comment: Yes, the data generated on the simulator gets recorded as well.

Comment: I tried the whole day, trying to record the data, but it doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: i logged so many events using the simulator, they didn't seem to appear on my portal, but when i logged in the iphone, it detects my session, but not my event.

Comment: Using the simulator, please ensure that you press the home button before closing the app. This is required in order to complete the Flurry reporting lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

Flurry proved to work for me including events, so it should work for you, too. I'd check with the debugger that the Flurry session was started (`[Flurry startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"]`) and your event code got really executed. And that you have internet connection, otherwise all events will get saved locally and transfered to Flurry on the next occasion.

Than wait some more, it takes time at times for the analytics results to show...